# How to retrieve image description title in C#?

Tags: c#, image, exif

I have a file with the following properties:

[image: Coral image properties]

I want to get the description title "Dragon's Eye Coral". How would I go about doing this?

I have been trying to do it with the following code but without any result:

```
public string GetImageTitle(Image img)
    {
        const int metTitle = 0x0320;
        var props = img.PropertyItems;
        var Title = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == metTitle);
        if (Title != null)
        {
            var myObject = Encoding.ASCII;
            var PicTitle = myObject.GetString(Title.Value, 0, Title.Len - 1);
            return PicTitle;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: The issue as I understand it is that `Title` comes under different Ids.  It's not always 0x320.

Comment: Ok, is there any way i can get it based on the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the below code and its working fine.. u just need to change the metTitle int value

```
        Image im = Image.FromFile("image file path");
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();            
        var allPoprItem = im.PropertyItems;
        const int metTitle = 0x10e;
        var Title = allPoprItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == metTitle);
        Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(Title.Value));
```

I am able to get the whatever title i set to an image.. try this..

Comment: Thanks, i appreachiate it but that didn't work sadly. Even if i loop through every PropertyItem i can't find the title.

Comment: Actually ... It must have been a corrupt image file I've been working with. Created a new file and set the title property on that instead and i get read that without problem... Makes me sad I spent so much time on this when it all was a corrupt file :/

Comment: @AndreasLjungström no issue.. it happens sometime.. bt atleaset we learnt something.. :)

Comment: You should use `Encoding.UTF7.GetString(Title.Value)`. That works for German Umlauts.